# Disable radio buttons based on value

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to disable radio buttons based on the value of a variable. The radio that is equal to the variable value should be disabled.

Ex:

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" />Value a
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" />Value b
```

So if the `$variable = 'a';` then the radio button which has the value `a` should be disabled.

Comment: you can get the value by $('input[type="radio"]').val(); then set  attribute disabled to true

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try -

```
var a = 'a';
$("input[type=radio][value=" + a + "]").prop("disabled",true);
```

or

```
var a = 'a';
$("input[type=radio][value=" + a + "]").attr("disabled",true);
```

If you're using an older jQuery version.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FtwcL/1

Comment: Good one, but you should use `prop` for setting and getting properties that evaluate to a boolean value.

Comment: @Shef - Am I right in thinking `.prop` will only work with post 1.6 versions of jQuery?

Comment: It works thanks but I want disabled to be added to the code like this `<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" disabled />`

Comment: @ipr101: Yes, but that's what the OP should be using either way.

Comment: @Ajay - jQuery adds the 'disabled' flag dynamically to the DOM so you won't see it in the code - if you viewed the souce code via something like Firebug you might see the 'disabled' flag added.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable based by name and value, you can try this

```
var a = 'a';
var fieldName = 'r1';
$('input[type=radio][name=' + fieldName + '][value='+ a +']').prop('disabled', true);
```